# Node js config smtp error

Tags: javascript

I am using *nodemailer* and I am getting an error:

> config smtp error

How should I properly configure nodemailer smtp  feature?

```
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let poolConfig = {
    pool: true,
    host: 'mail.smtp2go.com',
    port: 2525,
    secure: true, // use TLS
    auth: {
        user: 'usmanghany6@gmail.com',
        pass: 'Usman12345'
    }
};

// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
    to: 'upercase4@gmail.com, upercase4@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A detailed SMTP nodemailer configuration documentation can be found here:
[nodemailer_smtp_doc](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/)

**Note:** Try to run the following config verification in order to get more detailed message:

```
// verify connection configuration
transporter.verify(function(error, success){
     if (error) {
         console.log(error);
     } else {
         console.log('Ok message');
       }
});
```